# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound when using line.split on the string

Tags: java, file-io, io

Getting indexOutOfBound. After sucessfull file save. I open the file to perform the following tasks: find the total costPerItem, totalCount and sum. Don't know why I'm getting out of bound. Error points out to

```
totalCost =+ Double.parseDouble(index[1].trim());
```

Source code:

```
 Scanner data = new Scanner(new File("registryCopy.txt"));

    while(data.hasNext()){
        String line = data.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        String[] index = line.split("\\t");
        totalCost += Double.parseDouble(index[1].trim());
        totalCount += Integer.parseInt(index[2].trim());

        sum = totalCost/totalCount;

    }
```

Error

```
Error: "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

which is: `totalCost += Double.parseDouble(index[1].trim());`

For some reasons it doesn't split the line.  Text file is as follow:

```
item1 15.00 3
item2 15 2
item3 14 3
```

File was created before and promted the user to input that data. Source for that:

```
while(userInput.charAt(0)!='n'){
        /**
         * Need only one PrintWriter out0 i.e, then I either use the userbased name OR fixed name creation i.e registryCopy.txt(true will
         * not overwrite the file but go to the next).
         */
        PrintWriter out0 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("registryCopy.txt", true)));

    System.out.print("Enter item name: ");
    itemName = kybd.next();//user String
    out0.print(itemName + " ");

    System.out.print("Enter item price: $");
    price = kybd.next();
    out0.print(price + " ");

    System.out.print("Enter item quantity: ");
    quantity = kybd.next();
    out0.println(quantity);


    System.out.print("Do you have another item to scan? Yes(y) or No(n): ");
    userInput= kybd.next();
    out0.flush();
    }//end of whileLoop
```

Update1: You guys are awesome, \s did the trick. Beer on me when you're in Chicago. Thanks

OUTPUT sourceCode:

```
sum = totalCost*totalCount;
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(totalCost);
    System.out.println(totalCount);
    System.out.println(sum);
```

SOP:

item1 15.00 3

item2 15 2

item3 14 3

item5 10.00 3

item 5 12

bla 11 5

bread 1 15

item14 5 3

76.0

46

3496.0

Comment: Welcome to SO.  +1 for a question with all the necessary information :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call of `split` splits on tabs; it appears that your input has some other kind of whitespace separating the tokens.

To split on any kind of whitespace, use `"\\s"`:

```
String[] index = line.split("\\s");
```

`\s` is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) that stands for any of the following: `' ', '\t', '\n', '\x0B', '\f', '\r'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program that writes the file puts space characters between the fields.  Your program that reads the file is trying to split the lines on tab characters, instead of spaces.  You have two choices.

1. Change the program that writes the file, so that it inserts tab characters - that is, wherever you have `+ " "` in the source, change it to `+ "\t"`
2. Change the program that reads the file, so that it splits the line on space characters.  That is, make it `line.split(" ")`.  Alternatively, you can use `line.split("\\s")` which will split on any kind of white space.